# After adding nodes in Apache IoTDB, why reported port number error?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I reported this error when I tried to start the second CofigNode and DataNode in the cluster of Apache IoTDB: `Parameter cn_internal_port can not be 10711, please set to: 10710. Because cn_internal_port can't be modified after first startup`. Shouldn’t I change the port when adding nodes? Why did the error message suggested me to change it back to the original one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you start both nodes in the same data folder of Apache IoTDB? If you want to start multiple nodes on the same server, you can manually copy multiple copies of the initial starte of the node(no data folder) and then change the port to start them.